# How much capacity should a static hash table have to minimize collisions?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

My program retrieves a finite and complete list of elements I want to refer to by a string ID.  I'm using a .Net `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` to store these elements.  I personally have no idea how many elements there will be.  It could be a few.  It could be thousands.

Given the program know exactly how many elements it will be putting in the hash table, what should it specify as the table's capacity.  Clearly it should be at least the number of elements it will contain, but using only that number will likely lead to numerous collisions.

Is there a guide to selecting the capacity of a hash table for a known number of elements to balance hash collisions and memory wastage?

**EDIT:** I'm aware a hash table's size can change.  What I'm avoiding first and foremost is leaving it with the default allocation, then immediately adding thousands of elements causing countless resize operations.  I won't be adding or removing elements once it's populated.  If I know what's going in, I can ensure there's sufficient space upfront.  My question relates to the balance of hash collisions versus memory wastage.

Comment: There won't be "countless" resize operations, indeed even for 10K items, there will probably be fewer than 10 resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bit of a subjective question but let me try my best to answer this (from perspective of CLR 2.0. only as I have not yet explored if there have been any changes in dictionary for CLR 4.0).

Your are using a dictionary keyed on string. Since there can be infinite possible strings, it is reasonable to assume that every possible hash code is 'equally likely'. Or in other words each of the 2^32 hash codes (range of int) are equally likely for the string class. Current version of Dictionary in BCL drops off 32nd bit from any 32 bit hash code thus obtained, to essentially get a 31 bit hash code. Hence the range we are dealing with is 2^31 unique equally likely hash codes.

Note that the range of the hash codes is not dependent on the number of elements dictionary contains or can contain.

Dictionary class will use this hash code to allocate a bucket to the 'Myclass' object. So essentially if two different strings return same 31 bits of hash code (assuming BCL designers have chosen the string hash function highly wisely, such instances should be fairly spread out) both will be allocated same bucket. In such a hash collision, nothing can be done.

Now, in current implementation of the Dictionary class, it may happen that even different hash codes (again 31 bit) still end up in the same bucket. The bucket index is identified as follows:

```
hash = <31 bit hash code>
pr = <least prime number greater than or equal to current dictionary capacity>
bucket_index = hash modulus pr
```

Hence every hash code of the form (pr*factor + bucket_index) will end up in same bucket irrespective of the factor part.

If you want to be absolutely sure that all different possible 31 bit hash codes end up in different buckets only way is to force the pr to be greater than or equal to the largest possible 31 bit hash code. Or in other words, ensure that every hash code is of the form (pr*0 + hash_code) i.e. pr should be greater than 2^31. This by extension means that the dictionary capacity should be at-least 2^31.

Note that the capacity required to minimize hash collisions is not at all dependent on the number of elements you want to store in the dictionary but on the range of the possible hash codes.

As you can imagine 2^31 is huge huge memory allocation. In fact if you try to specify 2^31 as the capacity, there will be two arrays of 2^31 length. Consider that on a 32 bit machine highest possible address on RAM is 2^32!!!!!

If, for some reason, default behavior of the dictionary is not acceptable to you and it is critical for you to minimize hash collisions (or rather I would say bucket collisions) only hope you have is to provide your own hash code (i.e. you can not use string as key). Such a hash code should keep the formula to obtain bucket index in mind and strive to minimize the range of possible hash codes. Simplest approach is to incrementally assign a number/index to your unique MyClass instances and use this number as your hash code. Then you can specify the total number of MyClass instances as dictionary capacity. Though, in such a case an array can easily be maintained instead of dictionary as you know the 'index' of the object and index is incremental.

In the end, I would like to re-iterate what others have  said, 'there will not be countless resizes'. Dictionary doubles its capacity (rounded off to nearest prime number greater than or equal to the new capacity) each time it finds itself short of space. In order to save some processing, you can very well set capacity to number of MyClass instances you have as in any case dictionary will require this much capacity to store the instances but this will not minimize 'hash-collisions' and for normal circumstances will be fast enough.

Comment: Clearly I'm looking at the problem from the wrong angle.  Thanks for that description!

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to imply a false assumption, namely that the dictionary's capacity is fixed. It isn't.

If you know in any given case that a dictionary will hold at least some number of elements, then you can specify that number as the dictionary's *initial* capacity.  The dictionary's capacity is always at least as large as its item count (this is true for .NET 2 through 4, at least; I believe this is an undocumented implementation detail that's subject to change).

Specifying the initial capacity reduces the number of memory allocations by eliminating those that would occurred as the dictionary grows from its default initial capacity to the capacity you have chosen.

If the hash function in use is well chosen, the number of collisions should be relatively small and should have a minimal impact on performance.  Specifying an over-large capacity might help in some contrived situations, but I would definitely not give this any thought unless profiling showed that the dictionary's lookups were having a significant impact on performance.

(As an example of a contrived situation, consider a dictionary with `int` keys with a capacity of 10007, all of whose keys are a multiple of 10007.  With the current implementation, all of the items would be stored in a single bucket, because the bucket is chosen by dividing the hash code by the capacity and taking the remainder.  In this case, the dictionary would function as a linked list, and forcing it to use a different capacity would fix that.)

Answer (score 1):

Datastructure like HashTable are meant for dynamic memory allocation. You can however mention the initial size in some structures. But , when you add new elements , they will expand in size. There is in no way you can restrict the size implicitly.

There are many datastructures available , with their own advantages and disadvantages. You need to select the best one. Limiting the size does not affect the performance. You need to take care of Add, Delete and Search which makes the difference in performance.